# symfony 2 create custom form how to get form custom element?

Tags: php, forms, symfony

```
$form = $this->createForm(new OrganizationType(), $entity, array(
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('_control_organization_create'),
        'method' => 'POST',
    ));

    $form->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Create'));

    return $form;
```

there is action and method defined. how to get this? in template engine twig into custom render?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By calling,

```
{{ form(form) }}
```

Or,

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
```

the `action` and `method` options values you added to your form definition are used.

**From the documentation ...**

Also, check [Building The Form section](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#building-the-form) of the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html) to see how to render the HTML form by passing

```
array('form' => $form->createView())
```

to the render helper within your controller.

Then, take a look at [Rendering the Form part](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#rendering-the-form) of the [same documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html).

**Also ...**

If you want to override them in your template, you've to pass the right values to your `form()` or `form_start()` helpers as follow,

```
{{ form(form, {'action': path('target_route'), 'method': 'GET'}) }}

{{ form_start(form, {'action': path('target_route'), 'method': 'GET'}) }}
```

Comment: i just need get custom render like this but how to get my custom array element {my action}, {my method}?`<form action="{{ path('task_new') }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
{{ form_errors(form) }}

{{ form_row(form.task) }}
{{ form_row(form.dueDate) }}

{{ form_rest(form) }}

<input type="submit" />
</form>`

Answer (score 0):

```
Return your form like this

return $this->render('Your Bundle name: Your controller name : Your twig file', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));


And in your twig file get the form like this:

{{ form(form) }}
```